# How to show data in table received from server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

I have a page index.html(with form and a table) and a php file name indexx.php
When I fill data in index.html for I click on button Get Data and request go to my file indexx.php. Now indexx.php take data from HTML page and request for some video using post method and I am receiving successfully Json data. But I want to show this data in my HTML page in a table format.

index.html

```
<head>
</head>
<body>




<form action="indexx.php" method="POST" >
<div class="container" style="width:100%;">
<center></center>
</div>
<div class="container" style="width:100%;">
<label for="userId"><b>UserId</b></label>
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter Your User Id" name="userId" autofocus required>

<label for="categoryId"><b>categoryId</b></label>
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter categoryId" name="categoryId" required>

<button type="submit" >GET DATA</button>
</div>

</form>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
  <table id= "userdata" width="50%" border="2">
    <thead>
      <th>VIDEO NAME</th>
      <th>DATE</th>
      <th>TIME</th>           
      <th>DURACTION</th>
      <th>LIVE STATUS</th>
      <th>LINK</th>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- here you will loop through the data you have received from curl and fill it in the tbody, and this entrie thing will be done when the page loads -->
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My indexx.php

```
<?php
$userId = $_POST['userId'];
$categoryId = $_POST['categoryId'];
$url = 'https://www.serversample.php';
$data = array('userId' => $userId, 'categoryId' => $categoryId);

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

print($result);

?>
```

JSON file sample that I receiving from another server

```
{"yourvideo":[{"Id":"55","videoName":"CLASS-3","date":"2 AUG 2015","time":"9:58 PM","video":"sCLKbhghghhgb","image":"https://img.youtube.com/vi/sjjZB4jjuhwc/0.jpg","videoType":"video","videoDuration":"02:08:88","liveStatus":"offline","testId":"0"},{"Id":"6985","videoName":"CLASS-4","date":"29 AUG 2018","time":"8:52 PM","video":"gtghnhyv","image":"https://img.youtube.com/vi/uygbnhjhg/0.jpg","videoType":"video","videoDuration":"02:81:18","liveStatus":"offline","testId":"0"}]}
```

Now I want to show this file in a table format in my index.html page

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```php
json_encode($result, true);
```

It will back associative array with data. Print with print_r and check without the second argument you will have object with keys.

Comment: Sir can you edit my code and paste here.Because I am new in programming

Comment: Just write `print_r(json_encode($result,true));` at the end of the file and you will get array in output. Paste in this place result for next steps.

Comment: Where ( I mean in which file) I have to use` json_encode($result, true);`

Comment: Just in `indexx.php`

Comment: I tried but nothing happen simply open indexx.php Json data

Comment: Sir please invest some time to edit full code and pass in answer section. I will be thanful

Comment: Hmmm. Are you clicked submit button?

Comment: If you'd like to learn something go practice, I will give you tips to achieve your goal.

Comment: Sir can you share your contact details

Comment: Sir please give any other soly given is not working

Comment: I will give you solution: make code like answer below, use my method in comments below, and print table with `echo` method and using array in php file. You must try to implement this.

Comment: Ok sir please give solution

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use .html files, use .php instead: index.php (your current index.html file)
There's no need for a processing php file (you are using indexx.php), as everything can be done in index.php, here is a simple example:

```
<form method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='formSubmitted' value=1>

    <label for="userId"><b>UserId</b></label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Your User Id" name="userId" autofocus required>

    <label for="categoryId"><b>categoryId</b></label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter categoryId" name="categoryId" required>

    <button type="submit" >GET DATA</button>
</form>

<!-- form processing STARTS here -->

<?php

if (isset($_POST['formSubmitted'])) {
    print_r($_POST); // you know what to do with this
}
```